# How to get 50 random documents from between 400 to 500 in a collation of 1000 documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using `skip limit and aggregate` but it's not working.

```
db.collation
.skip(400)
.limit(100)
.aggregate([{$sample: {size: 50}}])
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Add skip and limit as part of the aggregate pipeline. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/#std-label-aggregation-pipeline-operator-reference

Comment: What does "between `400` and `500` mean? Without a sort the results are undefined and indeterminate

Comment: @user20042973 It refers to documents (400 to 500) in a collection of 1000 documents.

Comment: Documents "400 to 500" doesn't have a meaning unless you apply an ordering (via a sort) to those 1,000 documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it as part of the aggregation pipeline:

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/LhTNE85OZVS

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $skip: 400
  },
  {
    $limit: 100
  },
  {
    $sample: {
      size: 50
    }
  }
])
```